# Azure Durable Function Orchestration GetInput Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, .net, azure, microservices, azure-durable-functions

I have an issue working on durable function 2.0.

First, I have the queueTrigger, who call the OrchestrationTrigger

```
 [FunctionName("StartOrchestration")]
        public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("TestDurableFunction", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] string queueItem,
                                 [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {
            await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestration", queueItem);
        }
```

I pass a json string as param of Orchestration function,
but the
context.GetInput();
always return null

```
[FunctionName("Orchestration")]
public static async void Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context) 
        {
            var input = context.GetInput<string>();

            var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrdenTiendaFacturarModel>>(input);

            var parallelTasks = new List<Task<string>>();

            foreach (var order in orders)
            {
                var task = context.CallActivityAsync<string>("BillOrder", order);                
                parallelTasks.Add(task);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
        }
```

any help?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue, for some reason the execution of StartNewAsync was to the overload who the 2nd parameter is for instanceId.

```
Task<string> StartNewAsync(string orchestratorFunctionName, string instanceId = null);
```

and I was expecting to execute this overload:

```
Task<string> StartNewAsync<T>(string orchestratorFunctionName, T input)
```

my queueItem was an string and for this f***ing reason the function took the first overload.

Comment: I having the same issue.  How did you fix it?

Comment: I fix this calling the orchestation function in this way.

`await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestration", input: queueItem);`.